# Why Tessnet2 can't extract text?

Tags: tesseract, tessnet2

I using `"tessnet2_64.dll"`
[image]

This is my code , extract text:

```
 try
            {
                var image = new Bitmap(@"D:\Tessnet2\C#\test2.jpg");
                var ocr = new Tesseract();
               // ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
                //@"C:\OCRTest\tessdata" contains the language package, without this the method crash and app breaks
                ocr.Init(@"D:\Tessnet2\C#\tessdata", "eng", true); 
                var result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
                foreach (Word word in result)
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {

            }
```

Result Output:

```
146: I-18110
47: 88
```

How can extract text `"Hello"`?
Thanks all.

Comment: Does it work if you change it to normal colors (black text on white background)?

Comment: i had try, but it still not ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resloved by changed from:

```
 ocr.Init(@"D:\Tessnet2\C#\tessdata", "eng", true);
```

to

```
ocr.Init(@"D:\Tessnet2\C#\tessdata", "eng", false);
```